# how to countdown using a button using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

i have created application for school students regarding the test paper. In this application there is  ***JForm*** and a  timer for 10 sec . in this ***JForm*** there is  Jtextfield1 , ***JLabel1*** and JButton. when the student press the button  the ***JLabel1*** will show countdown from  10 , 9, to 0 . Then ***JTextField1*** will not be enable to edit or enter any data. And need to get a message that "timeup"

Following is my code i tried . but i am not getting the correct method which i am thinking .

```
for(int i= 10; i>=0; i--)
{


    if(i==0)
    {
        jTextField1.enableInputMethods(false);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "time up");


    }
    else
    {
         jLabel3.setText(""+i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to do it.

E.g:

```
private void startBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    startBtn.setEnabled(false);
    textField.setEditable(true);
    timeLbl.setText("10");

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        int t = 9;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // each second this function will be called

            timeLbl.setText("" + t);
            if (t == 0) {
                startBtn.setEnabled(true);
                textField.setEditable(false);
                timeLbl.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame.this, "time up");
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();// Stop the timer
            }
            t--;
        }
    });
    timer.start();// Start the timer
}
```